# Sending JSON data (query) from client connection in socket.io to server

Tags: javascript, socket.io, ejs

I'm trying to send a JSON object from `active.ejs`(client) to `index.js`(server) when a socket connection is established.

However, the query parameter of the socket object sent to the server isn't the JSON object (it's an empty object) I passed when I try to log the socket object in the server.

**active.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Active</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/tune-in', {query: "<%= user_info %>"}); %></script>
    <p>
      Welcome,
      <%= user_info.uri %>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how the `user_info` object is passed from **controller.js** to the above html(ejs) file **active.ejs**

```
  app.get('/tune-in', function(req, res){
    res.render('active', {user_info: user_data});
  });
```

Here's what the `user_info` object looks like -

```
{ country: 'US',
  display_name: 'My name',
  email: 'myname@gmail.com',
  external_urls: { spotify: 'https://open.spotify.com/user/randomnums' },
  followers: { href: null, total: 3 },
  href: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/randomnums',
  id: 'randomstring',
  images:
   [ { height: null,
       url: 'myimg',
       width: null } ],
  product: 'premium',
  type: 'user',
  uri: 'spotify:user:randomstring' }
```

**index.js** - Where the above JSON data should be logged

```
var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('Made socket connection', socket);
});
```

When I log the socket object, the query parameter looks like -

```
query:
      { '[object Object]': 'undefined',
        EIO: '3',
        transport: 'polling',
        t: 'LrEFaoW' } },
```

My intended usage is being able to do something like `socket.broadcast.emit('users', data);` in `index.js` where `data` is a JSON object containing a few of the fields of the `user_info` (or the query object).

And in **active.ejs**, I'd like to do something like -

```
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/tune-in', {query: "<%= user_info %>"}); %>
  var active = document.getElementById('active');
  socket.on('users', function(data){
    active.innerHTML += "<li><em>" + data.display_name + " is connected" + "</em></li>";
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** The above mentioned possible duplicate did not solve my problem, ie replacing `{query: "<%= user_info %>"}` with `{query: "<%-JSON.stringify(user_info)%>"}` didn't solve the issue. Instead I got errors saying `UnexpectedIdentifier` on the client side.

**EDIT2** The error was with `{query: "<%-JSON.stringify(user_info)%>"}` the double quotes " " around `<%-JSON.stringify(user_info)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your EJS template to the following:

```
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/tune-in', {
    query: <%- JSON.stringify(user_info) %>
  });
</script>
```

Note the `<%-` instead of `<%=`